# Get List Item by GUID

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I am working on sharepoint-2010 and I am new to sharepoint.
I want to access List Item by Guid. So, how can I access.
Please provide some reference or some class file to access that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [SPList.GetItemByUniqueId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyuniqueid.aspx) method:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists[listTitle];
        SPListItem item = list.GetItemByUniqueId(itemGuid);
    }
}
```